# cURL - How to send and fetch data in Wordpress

Tags: curl

**BACKGROUND**

After the user on *domain1* clicks a link to *domain 2*, I need to **send also the user-data (username,email,..) from server1/domain1 to server2/domain2** and to save it temporary in the server2/database.

Both are wordpress websites.

**CURRENT WORK**

Lets say, `$url = 'http://my-domain2.com'`;
So far I found out, that cURL can do this job:

```
function curlTest($url, $fields){

  try{

      $ch = curl_init($url);

      if (!$ch)
        throw new Exception('Failed to initialize');

      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT , 10);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Length: ' . strlen($fields)));
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
      $response = curl_exec($ch);

      $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

      if (!$response)
        throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));


      curl_close( $ch );
      return (int) $status; //status 200 = success


      } catch(Exception $e) {

          trigger_error(sprintf(
              'Curl failed with error #%d: %s',
              $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()),
              E_USER_ERROR);

      }
}
```

or objective orientated like descriped [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code).

Later I found a **wordpress solution** like this:

```
 $response = wp_remote_post( &url, array( 'data' => $fields) );
```

explained [here](https://deliciousbrains.com/php-curl-how-wordpress-makes-http-requests/).

The cURL call seems to be successfully, but I have no idea how to fetch the data on the other server.
So far I put the user-data on server1 in an array (*$fields*) and using POST to send it to server2. But **how can I fetch the data** on server2?

According to the example of Ed Cradock below the [offical documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/function.curl-setopt.php) it seems to be possible to grap the request on the other side with this code:

```
   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT') 
    { 
       parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $requestData); 

       print_r($requestData); 

       // Save requested Data to database here
    }
```

But it doesn't work for me because I guess the URL is wrong: `http://my-domain2.com/<whats-here?>`

**QUESTION**

How to fetch the Data of a POST cURL request with wordpress in a secure way?

Comment: How is your question connected with WordPress? And, please, ask one question at a time.

Comment: Ok, I made one question. And I do not know the wordpress way of cURL

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using curl directly instead of the WP HTTP APIs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[wp_remote_get()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_get/)
and [wp_remote_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_post/) and [wp_remote_request()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_request/) should answer on your questions.This is best practice for WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

`wp_remote_post`, which is better to use than calling curl directly, is sending a POST request to the other side, which means you can just fetch it with the `$_POST` global. There is no reason or need to use PUT requests for what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks! I researched already a lot, but I can't find an example, of how to fetch the data on the other server. How can I listen on server2 for data from server1? I guess i have to wrtie my own api? Is there some documentation? Simple if($_POST['username']){ //dosomething} will not work i guess